# NativeScript cannot override ActionBar "preview"

Tags: angular, nativescript

I've got a NativeScript 6.0.x app and I have a list component in which I navigate to via a route. Once I get there the ActionBar displays "Preview" even though I have it set to "Listing".

list.component.html file

```
<ActionBar title="Listing"></ActionBar>
<Label text="Hello world"></Label>
```

list.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "gr-list",
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "./list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./list.component.css"]
})

export class ListComponent { }
```

[image: preview screenshot]

Comment: Can you share the Playground link?

Comment: This is a locally developed app not on the playground site, so I don't have a link or a way to import it into playground

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the NativeScriptCommonModule. I didn't have a separate module for listing when I really should of. I was cheating having my imports in my app-routing module. Now it looks like this;

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "nativescript-angular/common";

import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular/listview-directives";

import { ListRoutingModule } from "./list-routing.module";
import { ListComponent } from "./list.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptCommonModule,
        NativeScriptUIListViewModule,
        ListRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ListComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class ListModule { }
```